# Mac OS X and Spaces, assign to keys

Tags: macos, mac, keymap, osx-spaces

Is it possible to assign the 4 or 9 spaces to some key combinations? Also that they do not interfere with another combinations?

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can assign any combination of modifier keys plus number (to go to) or arrow (to move) keys to switch spaces?

Through System Preferences -> Expose & Spaces, keyboard shortcuts are at the bottom. By default you can only select one modifier, but if you hold down one or two modifiers when opening the drop-down list, it'll let you set it as a combination.

Comment: i mean, how to use applescript to tell "open application XXX in space nu,ber YYY"

Comment: Ah - I see. No idea on that one, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar thing on stack overflow... may not be exactly what you want but it uses applescript to open apps in the applications folder to a particular space.

It's rather programming technical so I can't help you much from here. :)
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305835/bash-and-mac-os-x-open-application-in-space-n)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [Spacey](http://most-advantageous.com/spacey), a free app I developed which gives you keyboard commands to move windows between Spaces?